# Longitud de datos para descifrado no válida Encriptación AES256 C#

Tags: c#, .net, seguridad

En una aplicación trato de utilizar las librerías de C# .NET del AES256 para encriptar información antes de mandar a una base de datos.

Al Encriptar funciona de maravilla, no hay problemas al encriptar ni nada. Pero la cosa cambia al desencriptar. Me sale el siguiente error.

> Longitud de datos para descifrado no válida

El código es el siguiente:

```
// aqui más arriba tengo el saltByte:
        public static byte[] saltByte = { 2,5,3,6,8,2,1,8,
                                    1,2,2,2,5,6,3,8
    };

        // AES256 SECURITY

    public static byte[] AES_Encrypt(byte[] data, string password)
    {
        byte[] encryptedBytes = null;
        byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                AES.KeySize = 256;
                AES.BlockSize = 128;

                var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltByte, 1000);
                AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
                AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);

                AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

                using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, AES.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                encryptedBytes = ms.ToArray();
            }
        }

        return encryptedBytes;

    }

    public static byte[] AES_Decrypt(byte[] data, string password)
    {
        byte[] DecryptedBytes = null;
        byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                AES.KeySize = 256;
                AES.BlockSize = 128;

                var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltByte, 1000);
                AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
                AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);

                AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

                using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, AES.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                    cs.Close(); // <- en esta línea me arroja el error...
                }
                DecryptedBytes = ms.ToArray();
            }
        }

        return DecryptedBytes;

    }
```

Estos son los métodos que utilizo al encriptar un string. Es lo que utilizo en este caso

```
        public static string AES_Encrypt_String(string value)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);

        byte[] encryptedBytes = AES_Encrypt(bytes, "lala");

        string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encryptedBytes);

        return result;
    }

    public static string AES_Decrypt_String(string value)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);

        byte[] dencryptedBytes = AES_Decrypt(bytes, "lala");

        string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dencryptedBytes);
        return result;
    }
```

Y en la clase principal donde la implemento:

```
            eProfesor DocenteP = new eProfesor();

        string jsonData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DocenteP);

        string encrypted = Security.AES_Encrypt_String(jsonData);

        string decrypted = Security.AES_Decrypt_String(encrypted);


        LogWriter prueba = new LogWriter("Data encriptada: " + encrypted + " Data desencriptada: " + decrypted);
```

EDITADO: Básicamente busco encriptar un objeto json para mandar a la base de datos.

Comment: Sería interesante ver como llamas al método de encriptado, para saber como obtienes los bytes de la cadena a encriptar.Yo de hecho he probado tu código y funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Modifiqué el post con el resto del código. 2 métodos para desencriptar y encriptar un string y de ultimo el lugar donde lo implemento.